# JointJS - Custom LinkView: How associate to my Custom model?

Tags: oop, backbone.js, jointjs

im trying to make disable the click event on links, this make a vertex but i need another logic for this event. This is my model:

```
var modelConexion = joint.dia.Link.extend({
  defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: 'modelConexion',
    manhattan: true,
    attrs: {
    },
  }, joint.dia.Link.prototype.defaults),
});
```

My custom LinkView:

```
var modelConexionView = joint.dia.LinkView.extend({
  pointerdown: function () {
    // LOGIC HERE
  },
});
```

So.. how can i associate modelConexionView with modelConexion? How modelConexion knows what view use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution of Roman Bruckner from Google Groups:

> if you put both in the same namespace the JointJS will find it
>   automatically.

```
joint.shapes.andydiaz.modelConexion = joint.dia.Link.extend({
  defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: 'andydiaz.modelConexion',
    manhattan: true,
    attrs: {},
  }, joint.dia.Link.prototype.defaults),
});

.joint.shapes.andydiaz.modelConexionView = joint.dia.LinkView.extend({
  pointerdown: function () {
    // LOGIC HERE
  },
});
```

Comment: how would jointjs know which view is associated with which model? say i want to extend Link, LinkView once more. How would jointjs know which view is with which model?

Answer (score 0):

Models are associated with views when instantiated, so it seems like you might want to do something like this:

```
var ModelConexion = joint.dia.Link.extend({
  defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: 'modelConexion',
    manhattan: true,
    attrs: {
    },
  }, joint.dia.Link.prototype.defaults),
});

var ModelConexionView = joint.dia.LinkView.extend({
  pointerdown: function () {
    // LOGIC HERE
  },
});

var modelConexion = new ModelConexion();
var modelConexionView = new ModelConexionView({model: modelConexion});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can define the view in the way you want an then in the paper define the linkview to be used as specified in the api http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper

The options object passed to the constructor may contain these properties:

```
...
* linkView - object that is responsible for rendering a link model into the paper. Defaults to joint.dia.LinkView
* defaultLink - link that should be created when the user clicks and drags and active magnet (when creating a link from a port via the UI). Defaults to new joint.dia.Link
...
```

Then, having a look to the GitHub source at https://github.com/DavidDurman/joint/blob/master/src/joint.dia.link.js look for *pointerdown*. This is my result:

```
  // custom element for link
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  joint.shapes.customLink = {};
  joint.shapes.customLink.Element = joint.dia.Link.extend({
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
      type: "customLink.Element",
      attrs: {},
    }, joint.dia.Link.prototype.defaults),
  });
  joint.shapes.customLinkView = joint.dia.LinkView.extend({
    pointerdown: function (evt, x, y) {
      var targetParentEvent = evt.target.parentNode.getAttribute("event");
      if (targetParentEvent && targetParentEvent === "remove") {

        // YOUR STUFF HERE FOR REMOVE

      } else {
        joint.dia.LinkView.prototype.pointerdown.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    },
  });
```